# Python3: multiple operators with same precedence

Tags: python

I recently started to learn Python.

And my friend asked me which value `3 < 5 != True` evaluates to.

As I have prior experience to javascript and c++, I answered `False`. (I was able to see false in both languages)

Because, operators with same precedence (`comparison`) works left to right.

So that `3 < 5` is evaluated first, which becomes `True` and `True != True` is `False`.

I believed it was right answer.

But it turned out it wasn't.

I ran this expression on my computer and it said it's `True`.

Am I missing something? or Python evaluates operators with same precedence in different way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `3 < 5 != True` is evaluated as:

```
(3 < 5) and (5 != True)
```

Since `True == 1`, this equates to:

```
(3 < 5) and (5 != 1)
```

Of course, both parts evaluate to `True` and therefore your result is `True`.

Chained comparisons are described in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent
>   to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both
>   cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

Comment: Nice answer, but maybe explain a bit more how `3 < 5 != True` equals `(3 < 5) and (5 != True)`.

Comment: @ChristianDean, I don't think I can explain it better than the docs, so I've included a quote.

Comment: Yeah, fair point @jpp

Comment: I think it's intended to work the same way as conventional mathmatical expression where a < b < c means (a < b) and (b < c) unlike other programming languages